# How to improve efficiency for data transformation from Mat to oclMat in opencv with opencl

Tags: opencv, opencl, gpu, cpu

I have written a function with opencv and openCL, and calculated the executing time.

```
GET_SYS_TIME(start_time);
ocl::oclMat ocl_in(src_img);
GET_SYS_TIME(end_time);
printf("data transfermation cost time=%lu ms, %lu us!\n", \
    (end_time - start_time)/1000lu, (end_time - start_time));

ocl::oclMat ocl_resized_src_img;

GET_SYS_TIME(start_time);
ocl::resize(ocl_in, ocl_resized_src_img, Size(ocl_in.cols/4, 
    ocl_in.rows/4));
GET_SYS_TIME(end_time);
printf("resized cost time=%lu ms, %lu us!\n", \
    (end_time - start_time)/1000lu, (end_time - start_time));

ocl_in.download(src_img);
```

ocl::oclMat ocl_in(src_img);the function of this code is transferring data from Mat(CPU) to oclMat. it cost six times than resize function. I don't how to shorten the time consumer of the data transformation from CPU TO GPU.

Comment: if the jpeg or compressed image becomes 20-30MB after decoding, it takes 10-20ms for a pci-e 2.0 x8 card to get the data. This is longer that re-size operation. If you can, do the de-compression in gpu, or optimize buffer for a zero-copy access(with map/unmap) but you need pointer to array, if opencv supports it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not familiar with zero-copy access, I can get the pointer of the data and I think opencv supports it. Can you give me an example of zero-copy access.  Thank you.